# UDP - Sending a multicast message and listening for response gives SocketException

Tags: c#, udp, multicast

I'm sending a UDP multicast message to find certain devices on the network. I then listen for a response on port 5001.

My workflow is as follows:

1. Send a multicast "find" message to the local subnet.
2. Any [wiznet](http://www.wiznet.co.kr/) devices on the network respond with an info packet which I want to receive

<strike>It all works fine on Windows XP, but on Windows 7, I get an exception of type SocketException: *</strike>

> Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

I can see the multicast message go out in [Wireshark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark), and I see the response from the device(s), but my code doesn't respond. My code looks like this:

```
  public void StartListen()
  {
      SendFind();
      try {
          IPEndPoint localEp = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
          UdpClient listenClient = new UdpClient(5001);

          UdpState s = new UdpState();
          s.endpoint = localEp;
          s.client = listenClient;

          //allow time for the find to work - aka clutching at straws
          Thread.Sleep(500);

          while (listenClient.Available > 0)
          {
              listenClient.BeginReceive(ReceiveCallback, s);
              Thread.Sleep(500);
          }
      }

      catch (SocketException e)
      {
          Trace.WriteLine("Could not bind to socket on " + _localPort);
      }

      listenClient.Close();
  }
```

.. and RecieveCallBack ..

```
private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    UdpClient u = (UdpClient)((UdpState)(ar.AsyncState)).client;
    IPEndPoint e = (IPEndPoint)((UdpState)(ar.AsyncState)).endpoint;
    Byte[] receiveBytes = u.EndReceive(ar, ref e);
    rxByteList.Add(receiveBytes);
    messageRxed = true;
}
```

** UPDATE **

So I have tried various ways of structuring this code. It seems that the problem is related to sending and receiving on different UdpClients. My exception was caused by creating a UdpClient to recieve immediately after opening one to send - adding a delay between the send and receive fixed this.

I have altered my code to use the same UdpClient for the send and receive, but I'm still not getting anything on the receive.

Comment: Obviously there is already a socket bound to port 5001. This may be an application already running, or your own code. Double-check that you're not binding multiple sockets to the same port, and try if a different port works.

Comment: I may be missing something obvious, but I'm fairly certain that isn't the problem. I have nothing else bound to port 5001, and the code works on xp. Also have tried this on a "clean" windows 7 machine with no joy

Comment: Actually, that's not where the exception is thrown, but rather where the exception is caught! The exception is thrown before that, probably by the call to the `UdpClient` constructor, or perhaps by the call to `BeginReceive`. Can you tell us which?

Comment: On what machine is the program that sends the multicast running?

Comment: Sorry - stupid mistake with the exception comment! It is thrown in the call to the UdpClient constructor. The weird thing is that if I step through the program from the start and "F10" that constructor call, no exception is thrown... The multicast is sent from my machine (win 7)

Answer (score 2):

Sorted! It was because my Sendpacket used "udpclient.connect", which restricts the receive to all data in the endpoint supplied to the connect method.